# Update Array With Database's New Information

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

**How do I update the groups array database's new info, rather than using the old info?**

So basically, I have a Group model object. It gets updated in another view.

But in my home table view controller, I have the following code.

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateAdded" ascending:NO]];
_groups = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[[GGUser groups] allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]];
```

This does not update to the new info that is in the database.

**Only, when the app is restarted, does it update with the database's new info.**

*So it basically uses only the info it gets since the app started up.*

Note: this question is slightly different to what it was originally, after gathering more info regarding the problem

Comment: Are you calling [tableView reloadData]?

Comment: I am not calling it at the moment. When I call that my tableView goes blank :P  @rdelmar

Comment: Hmm... that doesn't make sense, unless _groups is nil or empty or there's something wrong with your implementation of the table view data source methods. I think we need to see those to be of any help. Have you logged _groups?

Comment: Actually the positioning of the reloadData call was wrong, but it still does not seem to make a difference, the info is still old, but it is new in sqlite, so I dont see what's wrong @rdelmar

Comment: Did you log _groups to see if it has data?

Comment: Yeah, I just did it, and it seems the new data is never added, just the old data is there, only when I restart the app is the new data there, although the new data is there instantly in the SQLITE db, hmm... @rdelmar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28776/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-gangstagraham)

Comment: What is in your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: ^basically every group in the list, basically from what I know now, the _groups list is not getting updated, so I need to know how to update it properly (although the actual database is updated properly which is weird)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a tableViews datasource is updated you need to call [self reloadData].

If you are already doing that, it could be that you are returning to the tableview controller via the navigation bar back button. This would mean that ViewDidLoad is not called again, and the _groups variable is therefore not updated.

I would try putting your _groups code in viewDidAppear, followed by a reloadData call on the tableView. If that works, I would then consider refactoring your code to use a delegate or a Notification to let the tableview know the datasource is updated

Comment: I am not really using a data source, I get an array of data from _groups, and then each cell gives detail about each individual group's info, so yeah, I am not sure if that means it is using a data source. Also, viewDidLoad gets called every time, because I have a custom navigation bar back button. The viewDidAppear did not work. :( Nice try though, I will keep trying to find a solution @RobertWagstaff